# Third-party cookie not set on Ajax request

Tags: php, session, samesite, third-party-cookies

When visiting `foo.com` the response of an Ajax GET request to `bar.co.at` includes this response header:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=i39mm1u7jh4tr7pmebue1k7abc;
            expires=Thu, 19-Nov-2020 20:34:40 GMT; 
            Max-Age=3600;
            path=/;
            domain=.bar.co.at;
            secure;
            HttpOnly;
            SameSite=none
```

A subsequent Ajax POST request to `bar.co.at` does not include any `cookie` header. But I need this header for having a session on `bar.co.at`.

Maybe that could be related to CORS somehow, or maybe to the cookie name `PHPSESSID`?

(It's the same on Firefox and Chrome 86.0.4240.111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is Third Party Anti Tracking (TPT) policy. So from this time, browser will not send cookies to third party domains from your domain.

https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2019/09/03/todays-firefox-blocks-third-party-tracking-cookies-and-cryptomining-by-default/

Some options to how you can resolve it you can find here : https://webkit.org/blog/10218/full-third-party-cookie-blocking-and-more/

Comment: I could not test anymore if this is the correct answer but I guess it is so I accepted it. thank you!